# In Typescipt Map use field of value map ad a key of main map

Tags: typescript

I have a map:

```
{ 
  '1': { id: '1', name: 'foo' },
  '2': { id: '2', name: 'foo' }
}
```

Id field of 'value' map is a key of main map.
How can I describe that fields link with Typescript?

Something like this:

```
interface Item {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

interface ItemMap { 
   [id: Item.id]: Item 
}
```

Comment: check describe? what do you mean? maybe show what you want in addition to the map

Comment: @konclave you want to ensure that the value of `id` in the inner object is the same as the key of the outer object that is enclosing it? I mean, in your example, to ensure that the first element has id '1'? Or, on the other hand, you want to ensure that any one of the 'ids' math with some key of the outer object?

Comment: @Sergeon i want to ensure that key of the first element is the same as id field of the value of the first element. It's like array of maps, but transformed to map of maps just to get the object by key and not to search it by id in array

Comment: @Ric sorry, it was a typo. How can I describe fields link